# Is it possible to change default overflow:hidden border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

When I use `overflow:hidden` on a container div with an image slider inside, it hides the overflowing content perfectly, but creates a white border of about 50px wide on the right side.

I want the images to extend all the way to the edge of the page, or as close as possible.

Is it possible to make the 'border' that `overflow:hidden` creates transparent, or make it narrower?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` does not create any border. There must be something else in your CSS that causes it to appear. Could you provide a live example?

Comment: Not at work now, but I'll post code later. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Add `border: 0` right below `overflow: hidden` to remove the border from that element.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Animuson is right. Overflow: hidden; doesn't add any border. If the images is a link, then it might have borders (but the default color isn't white). 
   But yeah, please add some source code for it. Without knowing the complete scenario, then something like this could possibly help you out:

HTML:

```
    <div id="section1">
       <img alt="foobar" src="the_URL" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #section1       {overflow: hidden; width: 100px; display: block; }
    #section1 img   {width: 100px; border: none; outline: none; display: block;}
```

## not tested...

Let me know if it helps or not. If it doens't, then please elaborate.

Comment: Figured this out - the outer container had to be set to width:100%, and the inner container set to 60px more than total page width, with overflow:hidden

http://www.benphilippi.com

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the way to fix this problem was to:

Set the outer container to width:100%,

Set the inner container to 60px more than total page width, and overflow:hidden

This reduced the 'border' (right margin whitespace) to any px width I set, as per the width of the inner container.

Code: http://www.benphilippi.com